# What is difference between the xpath and xpathselect in asp.net datalist?

Tags: asp.net

I got this question from programming asp.net and web-site called quickstart.asp.net.
In this it is mentioned that xpath and xpathselect is how used and syntex but it is not mentioned how it differs in work, i ckecked but both are giving same result.

Answer (score 0):

`XPathSelect()`  and `XPath()` have different return types.

From MSDN,

[XPathSelect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f902wc3.aspx)

> returns a node collection that
>   implements the IEnumerable interface.

[XPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73yw7ttd.aspx) returns

> An object that results from the
>   evaluation of the data-binding
>   expression.